# Generate Field with Options based on input field date check

Tags: php, jquery

I really need some help as this is my first time trying jquery, other than the plug-in datepicker. I have this user input field which is a datepicker.  I'd like to check that date input to see if it falls during the week or on the weekend (sat and sun). Then based on the check an input field 'Location' is generated with option(s).

If it doesn't fall on the weekend then 'Location' options are.  1. Airport Office 2. City Office.
Else if it falls on the weekend the only option is 1. Airport Office.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: So, where did you stuck?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but this is my code thus far.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Aintgettinit/pen/RwjXoVR

Comment: OK I've updated my script. The issue I currently have is that upon selecting the date from the datepicker the options are generated correctly, but it automatically selects the first option.  I'd like there to be no change until the drop down menu is selected, then you could see the options.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code fragment you have problems with?